# How to setup macbook disable battery and only turn on when plugged power adapter

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, battery

My MacBook Air 2011 model's battery is broken, often can't be charged, and remains at 1%. Can I disable the use of battery, and only turn it on when it's plugged in with a power adapter?

Sometimes when it's plugged in it's still showing "not charging" and displaying 1%, and operates very slowly. So I guess if I can always only use the power adapter, it can be faster than 1% "low battery mode".

I can't find any related setting in Preferences. Please help, thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding what you want to achieve. If the battery is generally dead, it is "disabled by default" - it will not work, and if it's weak it will charge always. So you basically already have the situation you described.

Comment: Let me make it more clear, I want my mac only can use when it plugged power adapter, like a pc notebook get rid of its battery.

Comment: That's the situation you have now, don't you?

Comment: sometimes when i plugged power adapter, it still can't shows "not charging" and 1%. I guess if not using battery, it will only use the power adapter only... u know when it display 1%, it get very slow...

Comment: You'll probably have to open the case and physically disconnect the battery however I'd suggest replacing the battery as the system actually runs better with a properly working battery even when plugged into an electrical outlet.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your MacBook Air **should not run slower**, even with a dead battery, **if it's connected to AC power**.

Secondly, **you really should replace the battery**, but if you don't want to physically remove the battery, the nearest option to what you want to achieve is to adjust your Energy Saver settings.

More specifically:

- Go to System Preferences
- Choose Energy Saver
- Ensure you have the Battery tab selected
- Now adjust your settings under the Battery tab to suit your needs (perhaps ensure they match as far as possible the settings under the Power Adapter tab).

You may also want to uncheck the option to show the battery status in the menu bar (as that will only be a constant reminder that annoys you under the present circumstances).

NOTES:

1. My steps above are fairly generic as you didn't specify your OS, however they should get you to where you need.
2. If you're certain your computer is running 'slowly' then it's quite possible you have something else going on.
3. Finally, you may want to reset your SMC for good measure. See steps below.

**Resetting the SMC on MacBook Airs**

1. Shut down your computer
2. Keep the MagSafe adapter (power cable) **plugged in**.
3. Press at the same time <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>control</kbd> (on the left side of the keyboard) ***and*** the <kbd>power button</kbd>
4. Let go
5. Turn your computer back on with the power button.